# How can I get last element of an array by using Destructuring

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6, destructuring

I am learning `ES6 Destructuring`

I am getting an error `Rest element must be last element`

Here is what I have right now

```js
const siblings = ['John','Jack','Amanda','Allie','Bob']

let [firstSiblingName,...middleAllSiblingsName,lastSiblingName] = siblings
console.log(lastSiblingName)
```

What I want is

```
firstSiblingName = 'John'
middleAllSiblingsName = ['Jack','Amanda','Allie']
lastSiblingName = 'Bob'
```

If I remove `lastSiblingName` then it works, but in that way I cannot get last element separately.

What I am doing wrong , and how can I make it to achieve the required output.

Comment: No you can't do with rest syntax alone, you need to take out the last element separately

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't, not with rest syntax alone - rest will always consume *all* of the rest of the elements of the array. You'll have to `.pop()` the last element instead, after extracting the middle elements:

```js
const siblings = ['John','Jack','Amanda','Allie','Bob'];

let [firstSiblingName,...middleAllSiblingsName] = siblings;
const lastSiblingName = middleAllSiblingsName.pop();
console.log(lastSiblingName)
```

Answer (score 1):

According to [mdn](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/rest_parameters) only the last parameter can be a "rest parameter". Instead you can do like this

```js
const siblings = ['John', 'Jack', 'Amanda', 'Allie', 'Bob']

let [firstSiblingName, , , , lastSiblingName] = siblings
console.log(lastSiblingName)
```